# Data input forms on lightning component basics Trail

Tags: lightning-aura-components, trailhead

I'm stuck... I have been trying to get to the bottom of this for a while now and assuming that trailhead is just super finicky about checking this one.. My component is working, but i'm getting this error when checking the challenge:

> The campingList component isn't iterating the array of 'items' and
>   creating 'campingListItem' components.

Hoping someone can rubber duck this for me better than I am at the moment..

here's `<c:campingList />`

```
<aura:component access="global" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">

<aura:attribute name="items" type="Camping_Item__c[]" />
<aura:attribute name="newItem" type="Camping_Item__c" default="{
                                                               'sObjectType': 'Camping_Item__c',
                                                               'Name' : '',
                                                               'Price__c': '0',
                                                               'Quantity__c': '',
                                                               'Packed__c' : false 
                                                               }" />

<lightning:layout horizontalAlign="spread" multipleRows="false" >
    <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small" flexibility="grow" size="12">
        <!-- CREATE NEW ITEM -->
        <div aria-labelledby="newItemForm">

            <!-- BOXED AREA -->
            <fieldset class="slds-box slds-theme--default">

                <legend id="newItemForm" class="slds-text-heading--small 
                                                slds-p-vertical--medium">
                    Add Camping Item
                </legend>

                <!-- CREATE NEW ITEM FORM -->
                <form class="slds-form--stacked">          
                    <lightning:input aura:id="itemForm" label="Item Name"
                                     name="itemName"
                                     value="{!v.newItem.Name}"
                                     required="true"/> 
                    <lightning:input type="number" aura:id="itemForm" label="Price"
                                     name="itemPrice"
                                     formatter="currency"
                                     value="{!v.newItem.Price__c}"/>
                    <lightning:input aura:id="itemForm" label="Quantity"
                                     name="itemQuantity"
                                     value="{!v.newItem.Quantity__c}"
                                     min="1"
                                     step="1"
                                     messageWhenRangeUnderflow="Enter a quantity that's at least 1."/>
                    <lightning:input type="toggle" aura:id="itemForm" label="Packed"
                                     name="itemPacked"
                                     value="{!v.newItem.Packed__c}"/>
                    <lightning:button label="Create Item" 
                                      class="slds-m-top--medium"
                                      variant="brand"
                                      onclick="{!c.clickCreateItem}"/>
                </form>
                <!-- / CREATE NEW ITEM FORM -->

            </fieldset>
            <!-- / BOXED AREA -->

        </div>
    </lightning:layoutItem>
</lightning:layout>
<!--iterate over camping List Items -->

<lightning:card>
    <aura:set attribute="title">
        Camping Items
    </aura:set>
    <p class="slds-p-horizontal--small">
        <aura:iteration var="item" items="{!v.items}" >
            <c:campingListItem campingItem="{!item}"/>
        </aura:iteration>
    </p>
</lightning:card>
```

Now this is working exactly as expected and new items are being added to the array of items, yet the error persists. I have googled many, many answers to this but nothing seems to come to mind.. crowd sourcing additional eyes here..

Comment: At the first glance, I can see every input element has the same "aura:id="itemForm". Please change the id attribute accordingly. It must be different for each and every input element of your component.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so the answer to this comes down to that classic Trailhead thing of being **exactly** correct in the syntax of what you're being asked to do.

I was iterating over an array as requested, but I had:

```
<lightning:card>
<aura:set attribute="title">
    Camping Items
</aura:set>
<p class="slds-p-horizontal--small">
    <aura:iteration var="item" items="{!v.items}" >
        <c:campingListItem campingItem="{!item}"/>
    </aura:iteration>
</p>
```

Note the attribute name on the campingListItem component of 'campingItem' - I named this differently to ensure not everything was just named 'item' - kinda made more sense to me to do it that way. However, Trailhead **expects** that it will find an attribute named "item", so the correct (passing) code is:

```
<lightning:card>
<aura:set attribute="title">
    Camping Items
</aura:set>
<p class="slds-p-horizontal--small">
    <aura:iteration var="item" items="{!v.items}" >
        <c:campingListItem item="{!item}"/>
    </aura:iteration>
</p>
```

Naturally, everything in the campingListItem component had to be changed to reflect the new attribute name also...

Comment: I made an account here just to say you're an absolute life-saver. This was driving me crazy.

Comment: thanks @Sinjai ;) glad i wasn't the only one that went nuts on this.. haha